# PayPal Checkout : LiveEnvironment class not found

Tags: php, paypal

I am making a website with PayPal integration and I'm looking at the tutorial ... In sandbox everything works fine, but in Live it's not working...

The point is, the payment is well executed, but then I try to retrieve the order informations and I get :

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\LiveEnvironment' not found in /api/sources/Classes/PaypalClient.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 /api/sources/Classes/PaypalClient.php(16): PayPalClient::environment()
#1 /api/sources/Controllers/PaymentController.php(116): PayPalClient::client()
#2 [internal function]: PaymentController-&gt;update()
#3 /api/vendor/pecee/simple-router/src/Pecee/SimpleRouter/Route/Route.php(119): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /api/vendor/pecee/simple-router/src/Pecee/SimpleRouter/Router.php(286): Pecee\SimpleRouter\Route\Route-&gt;renderRoute(Object(Pecee\Http\Request))
#5 /api/vendor/pecee/simple-router/src/Pecee/SimpleRouter/SimpleRouter.php(52): Pecee\SimpleRouter\Router-&gt;routeRequest()
#6 /api/sources/autoload.php(23): Pecee\SimpleRouter\SimpleRouter::start()
#7 /api/autoloader.php(7): require_once('/home/soinsdesz...')
#8 /api/public/index.php in <b>/api/sources/Classes/PaypalClient.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
```

This is my PaypalClient.php class :

```
<?php

use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\LiveEnvironment;

class PayPalClient
{
    /**
     * Returns PayPal HTTP client instance with environment that has access
     * credentials context. Use this instance to invoke PayPal APIs, provided the
     * credentials have access.
     */
    public static function client()
    {
        return new PayPalHttpClient(self::environment());
    }

    /**
     * Set up and return PayPal PHP SDK environment with PayPal access credentials.
     * This sample uses SandboxEnvironment. In production, use LiveEnvironment.
     */
    public static function environment()
    {
        return (ENV === "prod") ? new LiveEnvironment(PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, PAYPAL_PRIVATE_KEY) : new SandboxEnvironment(PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, PAYPAL_PRIVATE_KEY);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok ... I found the solution ... So ...

In the tutorial it's said : "use *LiveEnvironment* instead" ... It's **WRONG** (thanks PayPal!!! Really) the correct class name is **ProductionEnvironment** !

Can PayPal modify his tutorial please : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/

Comment: Thanks for this! I was also deceived by their documentation 

Comment: Thank god for StackOverflow, and c'mon PayPal! Wtf. Just what you need: a typo for going to production state, and to have to find the answer in a SO comment. 

Comment: Yeah ... I know, I tried to send a message to PayPal to make them know their error but never received any notification ... -_-

Comment: I hate PayPal, I really do.

Comment: It's August 2020 and they still have not updated this on the paypal dev page. Paypal's dev documentation is crap, and their website is littered with 404 links all over the place.

Comment: February 2021: the dev documentation still inaccurate. Use "ProductionEnvironment" instead of "LiveEnvironment". The existing classes are here: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK/tree/develop/lib/PayPalCheckoutSdk/Core